# How to open NFC tags on Windows like a mobile phone would?

Tags: windows, nfc

Is there a pre-existing setting I can enable to use connected PC/SC contactless readers to open NFC Type 4 (and others, if reader supports) tags with NDEF payload on Windows 10+? If there's no such built-on feature, presumably it can be added by installing something? Basically that would make Windows behave like a mobile phone.

Comment: I have edited your question to give it a chance to be reopened. Please add info about your research using the [Edit] button.

Comment: Scratching my own itch here: https://github.com/martinpaljak/NFC4PC/tree/main#readme